# What is the difference between Scala's Set() and Set.empty?

Tags: scala, set

What is the difference between `Set()` and `Set.empty` in Scala?

Which is more canonical and which is more performant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Set()` is actually calling `Set.empty` under the hood, so the latter is a tiny fraction more performant:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.scala#L49

Also, you may prefer `Set.empty` because of better readability.

Answer (score 2):

I found an implementation of Set.empty, it's probably a bit more efficient.

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L1

Personnaly I prefer to use named factory methods instead of constructors, but one could argue that it's more verbose and useless.
It's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

casually set s are empty
Set() is actually calling Set.empty under the hood, so the latter is a tiny fraction more performant: